# Pygame doesnt work in PyCharm on Windows 10

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

I've managed to install pygame on my stationary computer, but when I want to do it on my laptop I get problems.

What I've done:

1. Installed Git
2. Installed PyCharm
3. Installed Python x64:
   https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.1/python-3.7.1-amd64.exe
4. Installed pygame with cmd cd
   C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37 python.exe -m
   pip install pygame
5. Added interpreter in PyCharm: C:\Users\bruker\PycharmProjects\CatAttack\venv\Scripts\python.exe

Error message I got:

> C:\Users\bruker\PycharmProjects\CatAttack\venv\Scripts\python.exe
>   C:/Users/bruker/PycharmProjects/CatAttack/Main.py Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/bruker/PycharmProjects/CatAttack/Main.py", line 1, in
>   
>       import pygame ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

**EDIT:**
I found out that the error was that I had "interpreter" as a virtual enviroment, and not system enviroment.. Case solved.

Comment: How did you do that???

Comment: @Mudkip: https://codingfora.com/python/getting_started/first_python_game_in_liclipse_with_pygame.php?course=python&module=getting_started&content=first_python_game_in_liclipse_with_pygame&l=en